# Using Scalatra 2.2.1 with Maven

Tags: maven, jetty, scalatra

Has anyone been successful for using Maven and Scalatra 2.2.1?

I found this old archetype https://github.com/Srirangan/scalatra-maven-prototype and tried to update the dependency versions, but I keep hitting incompatibility issues.

I'd like to use:

1. Scalatra 2.2.1
2. Scala 2.10

I think that Jetty has some problems to run the produced war.

I would highly appreciate your help on this one.

Here's the example project which I am using:
http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html

And my current pom.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-scalatra-web-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <scalatra.version>2.2.1</scalatra.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>scalatra-maven-prototype</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.17</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra-scalate_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra-specs2_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.20100224</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>SonatypeNexusSnapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>FuseSourceSnapshotRepository</id>
            <name>FuseSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ScalaToolsMaven2Repository</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok after a lot of crying, I found the correct versions to use, and the correct artifacts.
Hope that it'll be helpful for someone:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-scalatra-web-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <scalatra.version>2.2.1</scalatra.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>scalatra-maven-prototype</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra-scalate_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatra</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatra-specs2_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatra.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.4.v20130625</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>SonatypeNexusSnapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>FuseSourceSnapshotRepository</id>
            <name>FuseSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ScalaToolsMaven2Repository</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: That would be the standard 'mvn compile' and 'mvn jetty:run'.

Comment: Would you mind to update your answer with latest versions of the various dependencies as well as later versions of scalatra itself?  I did give you an upvote to engender some "good will" in this regard ;)

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but I can't promise anything at the moment :-(

Comment: @javadba well... things got busier than I thought. Sorry for that. Is it something that you still need?

Comment: scalatra is long gone off my list.